# Guidance on git branching/release strategy

Tags: git, azure-devops, branching-and-merging

I'm looking for guidance on a git branching/release strategy that doesn't seem to be like any of the strategies I've found so far.

We are using VSTS and currently have a master branch with feature branches for every change.  A PR is submitted to review the feature branch and, if approved, automatically merge into master.  That automatically triggers a release to the DEV environment.  Assuming everything's successful, a release is manually triggered to production (with approval).

The problem I've got is that we can have multiple team members working on various features at any given point in time.  That means multiple merges into master with a corresponding release to DEV.  All that works fine.  Issues arise, however, when someone wants to move their changes to production before everyone else's changes are ready. In our current scenario, performing the release to production pulls in everything from the master branch that existed at the time of the release to DEV.

That might seem very wrong, but our Git repo doesn't really contain code - think of it more as configuration.  It's perfectly acceptable to move configuration changes to production independently.

I've looked into having multiple branches and cherry-picking commits but that feels overly complicated.

I'm hoping I'm missing something pretty obvious.

Comment: Are Production and Dev two separate environments in Vsts? Do you generate artifacts after Pull request?

Comment: Yes, Production and Dev are two separate environments.  The build that runs after a successful merge into master generates artifacts from the current contents of that branch, which may include changes that have already been merged by other developers.

Comment: Is it possible to post a screen shot of your build and deploy steps in VSTS? 
If screenshot is not possible, can you list the build and release steps? Also can I know what sort of config is there in the repo? It will be easier to solve your problem.

Comment: I can't post a screen shot, but the build steps are pretty straight forward.  Since there's no actual code to build, the build step simply takes the artifacts from the repo and publishes a drop.  One of the files in that drop is actually a bash script that is used to apply the configuration in the environment, so the release just contains a single step that runs that bash script.  FWIW, the configuration that is actually being applied is a set of AWS Cloud Formation templates.  I'm not sure what you're asking when you say "config in the repo".

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you know this already, but

> That might seem very wrong, but our Git repo doesn't really contain code - think of it more as configuration. It's perfectly acceptable to move configuration changes to production independently.

conflicts with your statement here:

> Issues arise, however, when someone wants to move their changes to production before everyone else's changes are ready

If your changes can be in a state wherein they aren't ready together, by definition you need some way to stage them separately. There are a couple of different strategies I've used in the past here, all of them revolving around the idea that merges to main and rolling out to production fundamentally deserves to be an atomic operation:

1. Reduce the time a change stays in the master branch without going to prod. If need be, roll back changes which are unsatisfactory. This is not a complete solution to me, because it doesn't give people access to your dev or preproduction environment for the extended length of time that they may need.
2. Keep separate Dev and Main branches, and be prepared to cherry-pick merges to main. This doesn't totally solve your issue, because in most scenarios, if multiple config changes can pollute one another in Main, they can also do so in Dev, which may change your test results (as they would in the current system).
3. Examine your development infrastructure and redesign it such that development builds can be tested properly without being merged. Then set up a (gated) continuous deployment strategy such that when you merge to main, you always kick out to production. This strategy can require a lot of work to get going, but is probably the closest to the production environments I've experienced in major companies without having a dedicated build infrastructure team.

Comment: Yes, I realize those two statements conflict which is exactly why we have a problem.
I don't believe your first option will work for us as changes may be staged in dev for an extended period of time.
So far, cherry-picking is likely the closest I've seen to solving our problem but I've been hoping for a better solution.  Most of our developers (who aren't really even developers) are unfamiliar with git and trying to explain cherry-picking will be a challenge.
I'll have to give your 3rd option some thought.  I think there are some possibilities there but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The gitflow I will suggest as below:

- Each developer works on their own feature branch
- When a developer finish his work, create a PR to merge feature branch into `develop` branch
- When the PR approved, merge the change from feature branch into `develop` branch. Then release will be triggered to deploy to DEV environment.
- When it's ready to deploy to production environment, merge `develop` branch into `master` branch for production.

And you can also refer [A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) for a more details branching model.

Comment: I don't believe this will really solve our problem because merging from develop to master will still pull every change which is no better than what we have now.

Comment: Based on your current flow, doesn't it deploy to production environment after merging feature branches into your master branch? If so, every change also contains when you deploy to production environment.

Comment: Besides, for the reason why there has an additional step to merge `develop` branch into `master` branch, is caused production environment usually is living environment, that mean the version on master branch should always work normally.

Comment: Yes, with our current flow every change gets deployed into production, but that's exactly what I'm trying to fix.

Comment: @MikePearce So you just need to deploy the changed files into productions environment? And it's mainly related with the release definition configuration not the branch structure.